# Show jquery slide down for single instance only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click share your thoughts the comments block slide down for each of its instance. What I want is that it should go down for only particular section and not all. Below is snippet of my code.
Actually I am creating all sections dynamically using php and there are almost 10-15 sections on my page and comments block is going down for each section even when i click a particular section.
So Is that possible, that only single block slide down when i click button irrespective of the number of sections my page has.

```js
$('.down').click(function () {

    // Set the effect type
    var effect = 'slide';

    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: 'up' };

    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 700;
     

   $('.card').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
```

```css
#comments{
       background-color: #535d92;
       display: none;
       height:60px;
           }

#slide {
    width: 90%;
    margin-top: 14px;
    margin-left: 14px;
 z-index:1;
    border: none;
 border-radius: 2.5em;
 background: #fff;
 -webkit-appearance: none; 
    outline:none;
 padding: 0.85em 1.5em;
 height:10%;
         }

.cd-container {
       width: 90%;
       margin: 0 auto;
               }

.post-footer ul {list-style:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <section class="cd-container">
   <div class="cd-timeline-content">
    <h3>raghav</h3>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur                         adipisicing elit.</p>
 <div class="post-footer">
 <ul>
 <li class="down"><a href="#">Share your thoughts</a></li>
 </ul> 
 </div>
 </div><br/>
  <div id="comments" class="card">
  <input type="text"  id="slide" placeholder="Hit Enter to            Send!" class="boom"/>
       </div>
  </section> <!-- cd-timeline --><br> 
       
 <section class="cd-container">
  <div class="cd-timeline-content">
    <h3>sharad</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur                         adipisicing elit.</p>
 <div class="post-footer">
 <ul>
 <li class="down"><a href="#">Share your thoughts</a></li>
 </ul> 
    </div>
 </div><br/>
 <div id="comments" class="card">
    <input type="text"  id="slide" placeholder="Hit Enter to           Send!" class="boom"/>
 </div>
 </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Only **activate the `.card` within the same section** of the clicked
   `share your thoughts` element. Procedure:

   Replace

   ```
    $('.card').toggle
   ```

   with

   ```
   $(this).parents('section.cd-container').find('.card').toggle
   ```
2. Also, to address your second concern that the sections are dynamic.
   If you mean the sections are loaded after page load such as using
   ajax then simply **change the hook of your click to the container
   element or document and let it delegate the click**. Procedure:

   Replace

   ```
   $(".down").click(function() {
   ```

   with

   ```
   $(".container").on("click", ".down", function() {
   ```
3. I noticed that you have multiple elements with `id="comments"` in
   your HTML. This is not valid because `id` names for DOM elements
   have to be unique. I'd suggest you change it to  a class and in the
   css change the rule for `#comments` to `.comments`

**SEE WORKING EXAMPLE HERE:**

```js
$(".container").on("click", ".down", function() {

  // Set the effect type
  var effect = 'slide';

  // Set the options for the effect type chosen
  var options = {
    direction: 'up'
  };

  // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
  var duration = 700;

  $(this).parents('section.cd-container').find('.card').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
```

```css
#comments {
  background-color: #535d92;
  display: none;
  height: 60px;
}
#slide {
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-left: 14px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2.5em;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0.85em 1.5em;
  height: 10%;
}
.cd-container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.post-footer ul {
  list-style: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <section class="cd-container">
    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
      <h3>raghav</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      <div class="post-footer">
        <ul>
          <li class="down"><a href="#">Share your thoughts</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="comments" class="card">
      <input type="text" id="slide" placeholder="Hit Enter to            Send!" class="boom" />
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- cd-timeline -->
  <br>

  <section class="cd-container">
    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
      <h3>sharad</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      <div class="post-footer">
        <ul>
          <li class="down"><a href="#">Share your thoughts</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="comments" class="card">
      <input type="text" id="slide" placeholder="Hit Enter to           Send!" class="boom" />
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Someone downvoted without leaving a comment. Wonder why?

Answer (score -1):

You should find the parent element and make a search for the comment section.

```
$(document).on('click', '.down', function () {
    //find the parent
    var $parent = $(this).parents('.cd-container');    

    // Set the effect type
    var effect = 'slide';

    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: 'up' };

    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 700;

    $parent.find('.card').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
```

I also change the click handler, because they way you was binding it it wouldn't trigger on dynamically added elements, only the once there on page load, and also make a good practice to go away from `.click()` and use `.on('click')` instead.

```
$(document).on('click', '.down', function() {
     //code here
});
```